# how to add the current time?

Tags: python, django

please help to solve the problem.

I send the form with the data. form contains a hidden field with the current date.

models:

```
class Diary(models.Model):  
    title = models.CharField(
        'Заголовок записи',
        max_length=100, 
        blank=False,
    )           
    date = models.DateField(
        'Дата записи',
        blank=True,
        null=True,
    )                       
    text = models.TextField(
        'Содержание записи',
        max_length=5000, 
        blank=False,
    )   
    last_edit_date = models.DateField(
        'Дата последнего редактирования',
    )
```

forms:

```
from datetime import datetime
class addMessageForm(forms.ModelForm):
    last_edit_date = forms.DateTimeField(
        widget=forms.HiddenInput,
        initial=datetime.now,
    )

    class Meta:
        model = Diary
        fields = (
            'title', 
            'date',  
            'text',
            'last_edit_date',
        )
```

a problem in that when sending data forms is updated data in the database. but the field is not updated last_edit_date.

in the browser field last_edit_date has the following view:

```
<input id="id_last_edit_date" name="last_edit_date" type="hidden" value="2014-09-03">
```

Comment: why don't you use `auto_now=True` on `date` model so it will get updated when modified?

Answer (score 1):

If the only thing you want to do is set `last_edit_date` to `datetime.datetime.now()` on save, then use [`auto_now`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/models/fields/#datefield) option of `DateField` class and skip this field in the form.